Not able to start Intellij IDE through terminal (Ubuntu system)
Intellij IDE was installed on my machine and was setting up my Spring Boot application which uses JDK 11 but on my machine JDK 21 was configure.
Even after making required changes in the project structure for JDK 11, the IDE could not recognise Java files.
So I followed this article https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/switching-boot-jdk.html.
And since then I am not able to start my IDE. (./idea.sh)
Here is the output in the terminal:

Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class com.intellij.idea.Main
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/intellij/idea/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0

IDE: 2024.3.1.1 Community Edition.
I tried to re-install the IDE and also change my JDK version from 21 to 11 which I was trying to configure but nothing worked as of now.
JAVA_HOME : enter image description here
enter image description here
Should I update the alternative also?

Either set your JAVA_HOME to jdk version 17 or higher version or update the alternative and remove JAVA_HOME

Hello Yash, I think you should create a new project and copy the .java into it, then compile (checking the package).

I did update the JAVA_HOME to a newer JDK-23 but doing so didn't fix the issue.
Further I updated the idea.sh file where I explicitly updated the JRE to the JAVA_HOME,
and now I am able to open the IDE.
I also wanted to update the idea file but it just contains some numbers so not sure how to update that file but IDE works for now.
